# Implement two interfaces with the same method signature but different return type

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

Lets say I have two interfaces:

```
public interface InterfaceA {
 public int getStuff();

}

public interface InterfaceB {
 public String getStuff();

}
```

Now I have a class that implements both those interfaces:

```
public class Testing implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB{
 public String getStuff() {
   return "one";
 }

}
```

My question is, will this compile? And if it does compile, will it run?

**EDIT:**

I did try this on my computer and found that it compiled and it did run, however when calling getStuff() the program terminates with an

> Unresolved compilation problem

Any ideas what Java is doing on a lower level here?

Comment: since you don't implement the method from InterfaceA, I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: `it compiled and it did run` : I don't think it will compile. Could you please post the code that compiled?

Comment: @Kartic probably IDE problem or project not yet build properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> will this compile? And if it does compile, will it run?

You might be surprised: It will not compile but if it did, it would run.

The Java compiler requires you to implement all methods which are declared in interfaces you declared on the class. In your case, you need to implement **both** `public int getStuff();` and `public String getStuff();`. If you don't, the compiler will show an error:

> Testing is not abstract and does not override abstract method getStuff() in InterfaceA
>   getStuff() in Testing cannot implement getStuff() in InterfaceA

Now, for the Java virtual machine, it would be perfectly fine to have both methods in your class. However, the Java compiler does not allow it:

> method getStuff() is already defined in class Testing

So your code won't compile one way or the other.

---

> Any ideas what Java is doing on a lower level here?

Let's go back to the JVM itself and do some evil stuff. Look at this [jasmin](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/) program:

```
.class public Testing
.super java/lang/Object
.implements InterfaceA
.implements InterfaceB

.method public static getStuff()I
  ldc 666
  ireturn
.end method

.method public static getStuff()Ljava/lang/String;
  ldc "Evil stuff"
  areturn
.end method

.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  .limit stack 10
  getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  dup
  invokestatic Testing/getStuff()I
  invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(I)V
  invokestatic Testing/getStuff()Ljava/lang/String;
  invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  return
.end method
```

We declare a class Testing which declares two methods with the same name and arguments, the only difference is the return type. It implements both interfaces and has a `public static void main(String[] args)` method which invokes both methods (`getStuff()` and `getStuff()`) and displays the results. And this program actually works and the virtual machine does not complain about anything.

Why does it work? The [JVM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html) defines the *descriptor* of a method like this:

```
MethodDescriptor:
    ( ParameterDescriptor* ) ReturnDescriptor
```

This descriptor is used (in addition to class and method name) to resolve methods at runtime. As it contains the `ReturnDescriptor`, it is fine to have multiple methods with the same name.

What about the compiler? The compiler does not identify methods using their *descriptors*, but using their *signature*. The [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) contains this:

> Two methods have the same signature if they have the same name and
>   argument types.
>
> Two method or constructor declarations M and N have the same argument
>   types if all of the following conditions hold:
>
> - They have the same number of formal parameters (possibly zero)
> - They have the same number of type parameters (possibly zero)
> - Let A1, ..., An be the type parameters of M and let B1, ..., Bn be the type parameters of N. After renaming each occurrence of a Bi in N's type to Ai, the bounds of corresponding type variables are the same, and the formal parameter types of M and N are the same.

Therefore, methods cannot be distinguished by their return type in the source code and the compiler prohibits declaring methods which only differ in their return type.

Answer (score 4):

**You cannot do that and it will not compile.**

Taken directly from [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html):

```
interface Fish       { int    getNumberOfScales(); }
interface StringBass { double getNumberOfScales(); }
class Bass implements Fish, StringBass {
    // This declaration cannot be correct,
    // no matter what type is used.
    public ?? getNumberOfScales() { return 91; }
}
```

> it is impossible to declare a method named getNumberOfScales whose
>   signature and return type are compatible with those of both the
>   methods declared in interface Fish and in interface StringBass,
>   because a class cannot have multiple methods with the same signature
>   and different primitive return types (§8.4). Therefore, it is
>   impossible for a single class to implement both interface Fish and
>   interface StringBass

Hence you cannot do that and it will not compile. In your case it will complain that the method is attempting to use incompatible type as both methods have same name but different return types.

Answer (score 2):

> Unresolved compilation problem

This exception occurs only when you try to run your programm with compiler errors.

And the reason for not compiling given as, you have not fully implemented all the interface methods. You only did for `InterfaceB` method, not `InterfaceA` method.

*Note:* If you are not seeing ant errors in your IDE, please restart or clean your project once.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface I1 { void f(); }
interface I2 { int f(int i); }
interface I3 { int f(); }
class C { public int f() { return 1; } }

class C2 implements I1, I2 {
  public void f() {}
  public int f(int i) { return 1; } // overloaded
}

class C3 extends C implements I2 {
  public int f(int i) { return 1; } // overloaded
}

class C4 extends C implements I3 {
  // Identical, no problem:
  public int f() { return 1; }
}
```

The difficulty occurs because overriding, implementation, and overloading get unpleasantly mixed together, and overloaded methods cannot differ only by return type.

Now Try this :- `interface I4 extends I1, I3 {}`

The error you will get :- **interfaces I3 and I1 are incompatible; both define f( ), but with different return type**

Using the same method names in different interfaces that are intended to be combined generally causes confusion in the readability of the code, as well. Strive to avoid it.

See [this](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ310_001.htm) link

Answer (score 0):

The "Unresolved compilation problem" is specifically Eclipse compiler feature (ECJ). This compiler can produce the compiled file even if you have quite serious errors in your code. As long as you don't run the erroneous code, you'll be fine. In your case as you have the problem in `getStuff()` method, Eclipse creates instead the method which looks like this:

```
public class Testing implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB {
    @Override
    public String getStuff() {
        throw new Error("Unresolved compilation problem: \n"+
         "\tThe return type is incompatible with InterfaceA.getStuff()\n";
    }
}
```

So as long you don't launch this method you are ok. Once you launch it, you have an error thrown.

If you compile with javac, it would not create .class file at all. So back to your original question, no, Java language does not permit this (Java bytecode however permits).

That's also quite interesting what will occur if you try to call the `InterfaceA` method which is absent at all (after Eclipse compilation):

```
public class Testing implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB {
    @Override
    public String getStuff() { // compilation error here, but class is still generated
        return "one";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        InterfaceA a = new Testing();
        int i = a.getStuff();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

When you run it, you'll see:

```
Hello
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: compileTest.Testing.getStuff()I
    at compileTest.Testing.main(Testing.java:12)
```

That is: JVM throws an `AbstractMethodError` when you trying to call an abstract method with absent implementation. From the JVM point of view `String getStuff()` and `int getStuff()` are two completely different methods and second one just absent in our class.